# Join tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join two tables but I want the result set to only show matches that arent in the right side.

Example:

**LeftTable**

- leftID   | PK
- value    |

**RightTable**

- rightID  |PK
- leftID   |FK

  select l.value

  from LeftTable l

  join RightTable r

  on l.leftID = r.leftID

I know this wont give me what I want, but I am just trying to find out which items in the left table DO NOT appear in the right side byusing the leftID foreign key relationship.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What if we do

```
select LT.value
from LeftTable LT
left outer join RightTable RT
on LT.leftID = RT.leftID
Where RT.leftId is null
```

SO join will return all the matching as well as those rows which are in left but not in right. With where clause we only get those rows for which right table left id is null.

Comment: Do you think it is good practice to give aliases as **RESERVED** words?

Comment: Well, we should never use reserved words. I will change to alias.

Answer (score 5):

You nearly have it, just a couple of minor changes - the join should be a LEFT JOIN, not an [INNER] JOIN, and you need to only return the rows where the right table is missing, i.e. its fields are NULL:

```
SELECT T1.value
FROM LeftTable T1
LEFT JOIN RightTable T2
ON T1.leftID = T2.leftID
WHERE T2.leftID IS NULL
```

Comment: Do you think it is good practice to give aliases as **RESERVED** words?

Comment: No... I assume the names of the tables have been changed to protect the innocent and that these aren't actually the names used in the production system. I'd certainly *hope* so. But I'll change it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from LeftTable where leftID not in (select leftID from RightTable)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LeftID
FROM LeftTable 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RightTable ON LeftTable.LeftID = RightTable.LeftID
WHERE RightTable.RightId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `exists`, as a preference to using `where not in`.  The `left outer join` with a check on the null state of the right is probably still optimal though.

```
select
        left.*
    from
        LeftTable as left
    where
        not exists (
            select
                    *
                from
                    RightTable as right
                where
                    right.RightID = left.LeftID
            )
```